# How to detect a change in resistance?

Tags: resistance, state-machines

I would like to have a circuit that can be controlled by two variable resistors, and it should use the value of the "most-recently-changed" resistor. How can I find out when one of the variable resistors is changing in value? I would like to figure that out and then flip a latching relay such that it uses that resistor for the input. Is this feasible using a circuit without a micro-controller monitoring the two resistors? what would such a circuit look like?

scenario: imagine a lightbulb that is controlled via a three-way switch. Now imagine the switches replaced with dimmers - the most recently adjusted dimmer should be the one used to control the lightbulb, the other one exists simply to allow adjustment from a different physical location.

Comment: How does the value of a resistor relate to an on/off state of a resistor?  Is it above/below a threshold for on/off?

Comment: How it looks depends on what you want it to do.

Comment: It may be possible, but the circuit would be so ridiculously complex as to be pointless.  If you are talking mains voltages then things get more complex again. A real world solution would use rotary encoders, not potentiometers, to get relative changes instead of absolute, and a central controller to set the output brightness.

Comment: If this is actually a situation where 3-way light switches are wanting to be replaced with dimmers be aware that you would be way better off just buying 3-way dimmers. They are made!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you have two variable resistors and you want to use the signal from the variable resistor that last moved? OK so far? You don't want to use a micro so the only real option is to have a circuit that detects rate of change of each resistor value and the one that last moved i.e. created a \$ABS(\frac{dR}{dt}\$) signal, would "trip" a SR flip-flop. The flip flop output drives DPDT analogue switch thus selecting either resistor A or resistor B.

OK so far?

You'll need a fairly sensitive differentiator circuit (probably formed around an op-amp) for each resistor and, each resistor would be biased with a current so that it produces a voltage signal to feed its differentiator. That gives you the ability to generate positive and negative pulses when the resistor value changes - the size of the pulses are dictated by the speed that the resistor changes value. So then, and accepting that small slow changes will not be detected, you can use a window comparator that looks for "going above" and "going below" thresholds - either one will set a SR flip-flop. The other resistor drives a similar circuit that resets the flip-flop.

That should work I think.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any *easy* way to do it without a microcontroller.

Find a small microcontroller that has (at least) two ADC channels, and use these to measure the two real resistors (potentiometers, rotary encoders, whatever). Use firmware to decide which is "most recently changed". Drive a [digital potentiometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_potentiometer) from the microcontroller to operate the actual circuit.

This is a tiny, two-chip solution. Anything else would require many more parts.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend to go for a micro-controller based solution using two ADC channels. Most probably a very small µC (with regard to foot print, memory size, electrical power usage and price) would be sufficient.

Depending on the circuit to be controlled it might even not be necessary to drive a digital potentiometer - as the µC might control the load e.g. by PWM.

The description of the task leads to the guess, that any simple circuit "switching" those resistors might suffer a certain usability flaw. Consider both potis to be set to 100%, now somebody plays around with number 1, setting it to 20%. Later on somebody turns number 2. Your circuit now switches immediately from poti 1 to poti 2 - that is from 20% setting to 100% resulting in an uncomfortable flash of your light bulb (if that's the load). The µC based solution could easily be programmed to overcome that issue.